# Measuring weight before the invention of scales

Tags: science-based, technology, humans

**Background**

Let us go back to 3000 BC. Assume that scales have not yet been invented for measuring weights. (if they have, then please choose a time and/or place where they haven't)

For the purposes here, a scale is either a lever with a pivot or a mechanism using springs.

**Question**

Assume that I have two irregularly shaped lumps of two different metals - these metals have different densities. I want to relate the weight of one to the weight of the other. This will allow us to trade.

Excluding machines that operate with springs or levers, how can weights be measured or compared?

---

**Note:** I have considered  weight experts. They are trained from an early age to tell which of two objects is heavier and provide some sort of measurement. This skill is passed down from generation to generation. I would prefer to avoid this solution but, if you wish to suggest this method, then please can you give some indication of how accurately a human can estimate a weight.

Comment: Could you describe your desired output? Also, all you need to build a lever is a stone and a piece of wood. There is no way you can go back in history before that was invented. If you have the need to weigh metal clumps, you're advanced enough to put a stone and stick together. Please read up on history as a world builder interested in the past to get a feel for it, 3000 years bc is not the same anywhere. Where? In the European arctic or in sumer? Big difference. They were having complex literature in the east while Stonehenge was build in England (most overrated achievement ever)

Comment: There has never been a time when men needed to compare the weight of pieces of metal and they didn't have scales.

Comment: @Raditz_35 - As I said, please pick a time or place. I wouldn't be surprised if some isolated Amazonian tribes hadn't experienced scales - even today. (I haven't researched this).  Remember that we are dealing with fiction. This takes place just before the invention of scales. The inventor receives great acclaim and trading is suddenly accelerated because of the invention.

Comment: @AlexP _ I don't think you can give solid evidence for this. There must have been a point in time when scales were invented.

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica: Yes, there was a point of time when scales were invented. It predates the bronze age. Scales were invented *in order to measure weight*. That's what *measuring weight* means: comparing the weight of the object to be measured with the weight of another object; that's what a balance scale does. (And the question explicitly says "lumps of metal"; the burden is on the querent to show an example of a civilization which had metals but no balance scales. Hint: won't find any. The oldest direct evidence for balance scales comes from the early 2nd millennium BCE.)

Comment: I think you're underestimating humans and you're also completely underestimating the sophistication of metal works and trading raw materials. If you see value in metal, you can build a scale. There is absolutely no time before that. At the very least, you can pick up two pieces and judge which is heavier if for some reason you're living in an empty void without sticks and stones. you will not have universal prices and a stock exchange to really put a scale into use if you can't put a stick and stone together. Ropes are super easy and common as well, especially in the amazonian jungle

Comment: A completely new point = new comment: if you want to give the inventor credit, don't go for the device, go for a standardized system that will catch on through city states. That's actually a plausible premise. But I'd think you have to give us greater insight into the structure and politics of your world. Also, I think building a plausible copper age/bronze age world is more complex. Figuring out a way to standardize weights and spread it should be the easy part. Could you go into detail about what your world looks like politically and so on?

Comment: I'll just point out that the lever is probably the first thing to be taught in a science class. Not everyone understands it immediately. Some people never understand the fine points. Just because we have learned and our knowledge of physics has vastly expanded, doesn't mean that anyone could invent such a thing. If we could bet, I would bet that most people who you asked on the street of a big city would not be able to construct a working scale without tuition, let alone use it to measure accurately.

Comment: Note: I have to go out and so won't be able to answer comments for some hours.

Comment: You should read up on history to get some intuition. People used to work with stone and wood all day long. Their survival depended on it. If you want to go for comedy, go ahead, but please state so. You're also talking about generation to generation in your post. Look, trade and metal, that has to be after stone and stick. You cannot present us with a world to start with. There are alternatives, yes, but we need something to go with. Perhaps start at the beginning, now to build a plausible world where b came before a. Currently, this isn't good world building

Comment: I don't think what you're looking for exists. Even your own suggestion of weight experts is using the exact principles you've forbidden by using their arms (levers) and muscles ("springs") to get an approximation of which is heavier. I'm pretty sure someone could still invent a crude scale without much trouble with only sticks, stones and maybe some vines or rope, because to turn those into something that works almost exactly like a scale you basically only need someone who is bored, has a lot of free time and who's challenging themselves to stack up objects without them falling.

Answer (score 4):

### Frame challenge: who cares how much it weighs?

Whoever is buying it is going to weigh it in their hands if they care at all, it will be a purely subjective measure. The exact weight of the object is more or less pointless before the advent of mathematics or coinage, what really matters is how much each party thinks it is worth. If you are making something out of it, volume matters but not precision weight and then only as far as figuring out what you can make with the given amount.

Answer (score 2):

Not a scale by your definition would be a piece of rope over a roll, and the weights at different ends. But that is the same *principle* so using this answer would be cheating.

For identical materials, compare volume. Use Archimedes' principle which led to the famous [Eureka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_(word)#Archimedes) moment.

The twin problems are that this compares volumes rather than weights, and that understanding why it works requires people to have an abstract concept of *weight*. How can they have that without a scale?

So simply give up on comparing weights, and officially compare volumes. Look at the history of [dry gallons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_gallon) or [bushels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bushel).

---

***(Follow-Up)*** *Thinking about it a bit, how about this:*

Build a catapult with twin buckets at the end of a single arm. Fire both lumps ten times. The energy imparted by the catapult will differ from trial to trial, but each time the launch velocity of both lumps should be roughly the same. Between tests switch the buckets. If one flies a longer distance 9 or 10 times, it is clearly heavier. If the split is 5-5 or 4-6, they are the same weight. At 3-7 or 2-8, the test is inconclusive, try ten more times.

Comment: It's already stated that the density is different in the op

Comment: @Raditz_35, and that means no way left to get it right without a lever/rope and roll or a spring.

Comment: @o.m. - +1 for your answer but , in response to your comment, then before Archimedes, no-one knew how to compare *volumes* of irregular objects.  Who is to say that he couldn't also have designed a weighing machine without levers or strings

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica, if there was such a principe, don't you think someone would have found it by now? Mechanics at the human-sized (non-quantum, non-cosmic) scale are pretty much played out, I think.

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica, consider this rube goldberg: a sufficiently large vacuum chamber. A piston throws the object with repeatable *force*. Then the chamber is opened and people measure how far it flew. No scales, no spring, absolutely unworkable in 3000 BC ...

Comment: @o.m.  - With a little modification, that could be an answer. No need for a vacuum chamber. For lumps of metal, air-friction is not going to be very significant.

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica, a device to deliver a reproducible shove implies decent practical mechanics knowledge. Having that without having scales sounds weird.